# Generate a low resolution PNG from SVG using javascript

Tags: javascript, svg, png

I wanted to convert an SVG file to PNG file.
But the SVG view box is "0 0 8268 5827" so it will generate a huge file.
I want to generate a small file from that SVG.
Can anybody tell me how can I do that?

I used Canvg like

```
var c = $('#export_canvas')[0];
canvg(canvas, data.svg, {renderCallback: function() {
        var datauri = data.quality ? c.toDataURL('image/' + "png", data.quality) : c.toDataURL('image/' + "png");
        window.open(datauri);
    }});
```

But it is generating big image.

Comment: you can use this library: http://code.google.com/p/canvg/

Comment: in the browser or node?

Comment: @DanielA.White I prefer within browser.

Comment: @Nicholas I am using canvg. But it is generating big PNG

Comment: @Harikrishnan why not scale down a *copy* of the SVG and then convert it?

Comment: Does adjusting the SVG height and width do anything?

Comment: @rfornal No it wont work. Adjusting height and width wont scale the image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found the solution.
There is a scale transformation available for SVG.

```
                var svgStr = $(data.svg);
                svgStr.removeAttr("height");
                svgStr.removeAttr("width");
                $(svgStr.find("g")[0]).attr("transform", "scale(0.09)");
```

where "g" is the top group tag.